# TypeError: Can't convert object to 'str' for 'filename' image augmentation

Tags: python

```
enter code here
path=('img dir')
#this is list of user defined function which is i made earlier
funs=[crop,resize,flip,h_flip] 
n=3
plt.figure(figsize=(10,12))
for i in range(n):
   random.shuffle(funs)
   fun=random.choice(funs)(path)
   plt.subplot(3,3,i+1)
   plt.imshow(cv.cvtColor(fun,cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
   plt.axis('off')
   path=fun

plt.show()
```

hello dear members
i am trying to image augmentation on single image rather than different image using user defined functions (which is stored in list) and getting this error

```
TypeError: Can't convert object to 'str' for 'filename'
Input In [21], in <cell line: 5>()
  5 for i in range(n):
  6     random.shuffle(funs)
  7--   fun=random.choice(funs)(path)
  8     plt.subplot(3,3,i+1)
  9     plt.imshow(cv.cvtColor(fun,cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Your `random.choice(funs)(path)` is CALLING the function and passing a filename.  Do those functions expect an image?

Comment: `path=fun` at the end of the loop is replacing `path` with output of a `function`. Is this intended?

Comment: (tim-yes those functions expecting an image ) ,(@MYousefi -yes this is intended)

Comment: Can you please explain what the randomly selected functions in `funs` do to a path?

Comment: image augmentation